# Display a bootstrap dynamic modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a modal when pressing the button "Vezi rezolvare"

[image]

I have the following code for the button:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center patrat-block">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/LogoProbleme/pg1logo-v2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Problema 1<br>
                        <small>Gradina</small>
                    </h3>
                        <p>Află dimensiunile grădinii</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <a href="probleme.php?id=1&category=g"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Problema"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Vezi Rezolvare </button></a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the modal content + php :

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_GET['id'])&&isset($_GET['category']))
        {
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $category=$_GET['category'];
            $sql = "SELECT cerinta, rezolvare FROM probleme WHERE id='".$id."'AND category='".$category."'";     
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $cerinta=$row["cerinta"];
                $rezolvare=$row["rezolvare"];
            }
                $_SESSION["cerinta"]=$cerinta;
                $_SESSION["rezolvare"]=$rezolvare;
        }
        }
        ?>
        <div id="Problema" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Problema</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Cerinta</h4>
                        <div class="well">
                            <?php echo $cerinta;?>
                        </div>

                        <h4>Rezolvare</h4>
                        <div class="well">
                            <?php echo $rezolvare;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Inchide fereastra</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

What this is trying to accomplish is to show a modal with some information in my database. I checked and the values are stored successfully in $cerinta and $rezolvare.

It seems like when the button is pressed, there is a fast fade and I am redirected to the top of the page, without showing the modal. I put an `<a href="probleme.php?id=1&category=g">` so I know what button has been pressed, but it seems like it refreshes the page and the modal isn't displayed. How can I let the modal be displayed?

Comment: You sure this doesn't have anything to do with `WHERE id='".$id."'AND` ? - That and if it's your actual code, would read something like `WHERE id=123AND` causing a syntax error.

Comment: The php code is functional. I tried to echo $cerinta and $rezolvare and the values from the database are shown. The problem is with the modal. I don't know any way of storing which button has been pressed without using that href='probleme.php?id=1&category=g' . I think the modal isn't shown because every time the button is pressed, the page is loaded again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting a `<button>` inside an `achor <a>` is not valid html syntax because it can't tell which one was clicked. Also the anchor has an `href` different than '#' so it's just redirecting you to `probleme.php?id=1&category=g`. You can modify your code as follows **(not tested)**:

> 1. Remove the button from inside the anchor and change the anchor to:

```
<a href="probleme.php?id=1&category=g" class="btn btn-primary"
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Problema">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Vezi Rezolvare 
</a>
```

> 2. Have the template of the modal somewhere in your html:

```
<div id="Problema" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Problema</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Some fine body
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Inchide fereastra
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 3. Modify your php to return only the body of the modal:

```
<?php
    // Some good php
    echo("
        <h4>Cerinta</h4>
        <div class=\"well\">
            {$cerinta)}
        </div>
        <h4>Rezolvare</h4>
        <div class=\"well\">
            {$rezolvare}
        </div>");
// The modal body is returned by php
?>
```

> 4. Use ajax to retrieve the modal body and subsequently open the modal. Something in the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Assign some id to the anchor say id="myAnchor"
    $('#myAnchor1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the modal
        var modal = $($(this).data("data-target"));
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var request = $.get(url);
        request.done(function(response) {
             // get modal
             modal.find(".modal-body").html(response);
             modal.modal("show");
        });
    }); 
});
```